# routing Issue in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am having trouble to invoke the component file from other folder. My routing entry is as follows

```
import { ServicesComponent } from './services.component';
import { ApiListComponent } from '../api-list/api-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ 
  path: '', component: ServicesComponent,
  data: {
      breadcrumb: "ServiceListings",
      sidebar: [{
            link: "apilist",
            label: "APIListings",
            position: 'right',
            showDelay: 0,
            hideDelay: 100 }]
       }
}];
```

when i click apilist the component ApiListComponent from the other folder to be loaded. Please advise what is the changed needed in the routing.ts file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're basically asking us how to define routes. This is covered by thedocumentation: https://angular.io/guide/router. Read it, and try something.

Comment: Hi subu. You'll get more help if you improve your question. Try adding all the related code - or even better make a plunkr that demonstrates the problem and post the link in your Q.

Answer (score 0):

```
const APP_ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/breadcrumb',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'breadcrumb',
    component: ServicesComponent        
  },
  {
    path: 'applies',
    component: ApiListComponent
  }
];
```

Try it

Comment: No luck Laxmipriya. To  recap we have two views. API view and Service view. Service view component is called during the onload event and API view is called when i click the link  "apilist". This were i am stuck